# Facebook apps redirects to 4oh4.php only on some browsers

Tags: http-status-code-404, facebook-apps

I have an a very simple Facebook app template that gathers up user details when entering them into a competition.

I recently deployed this for a customer, but when they access the https://apps.facebook.com/name URL, they are redirected to:

http://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

This is only happening on some PCs.

I can't re-produce it on any browser or PC that I have.

I've also used the Debug tool at:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

and I see that the Facebook parser can access the app on my server and picks up the correct HTML content.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Caching problem? Somewhere, some server thinks that your app doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of things re. this. I changed the src address of the content, so the FB Linter might re-cache it, but that didn't work.

In the end, I just created a new app with a new namespace, and send it off to the client. It worked. I guess they must have been accessing the URL through a particularly useless proxy server, which was serving them up the same content 24 hours later.

Typically, proxy servers won't cache http 404 or 500 errors, but in this case, you're not getting a real 404 error, rather a Facebook HTTP 200 response that is posing as a 404 error.

Not very clever on Facebook's part.